# PHP String functions for long strip of data

Tags: php

i need to fetch data from the following strings and need to place their values according to their type

1)
***Response: Success Message: Mailbox Message Count Mailbox: 6000 UrgMessages: 0 NewMessages: 5 OldMessages: 12***

**Required Output:** example OLD= 12 NEW=5 URGENT=0

2)
 Name       : 6000
  Secret       : 
  MD5Secret    : 
  Context      : DLPN_Admin
  Language     :
  AMA flags    : Unknown
  Transfer mode: open
  MaxCallBR    : 384 kbps
  CallingPres  : Presentation Allowed, Not Screened
  Call limit   : 2147483647
  Callgroup    : 1
  Pickupgroup  : 1
  Callerid     : "Arham Ali" <6000>
  ACL          : No
  Sess-Timers  : Accept
  Sess-Refresh : uas
  Sess-Expires : 1800 secs
  Sess-Min-SE  : 90 secs
  Codec Order  : (ulaw:20,gsm:20)
  Auto-Framing:  No

**Required Output:** CallerId="Arham Ali" Name= "6000"

I am very much stuck with this stupid thing for so long please help me in PHP domain.

Comment: you should include source code that you have tried so far in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a bit more incase the message string is not always the same you could do this

```
$string = ' Response: Success Message: Mailbox Message Count Mailbox: 6000 UrgMessages: 0 NewMessages: 5 OldMessages: 12';


preg_match('/OldMessages: (\d+)*/', $string, $oldMessages);
preg_match('/NewMessages: (\d+)*/', $string, $newMessages);
preg_match('/UrgMessages: (\d+)*/', $string, $urgent);
preg_match('/Mailbox: (\d+)*/', $string, $currentMailboxCount);

print 'OLD= '.$oldMessages[1].' NEW='.$newMessages[1].' URGENT='.$urgent[1];
```

This is all using regex.  [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

The same methods would apply for the second half of your question.

A good tool to play with regex is http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Hoep this helps you out!

Answer (score 1):

RegEx would be best guess

---

### PHP

```
$string = 'Response: Success Message: Mailbox Message Count Mailbox: 6000 UrgMessages: 0 NewMessages: 5 OldMessages: 12'; 
preg_match('/Response: Success Message: Mailbox Message Count Mailbox: (\d+) UrgMessages: (\d+) NewMessages: (\d+) OldMessages: (\d+)/',$matches);
print 'OLD=' . $matches[4] . ' NEW=' . $matches[3] . ' URGENT=' . $matches[2];
```

---

### PHP

```
$string = 'Name : 6000 Secret : MD5Secret : Context : DLPN_Admin Language : AMA flags : Unknown Transfer mode: open MaxCallBR : 384 kbps CallingPres : Presentation Allowed, Not Screened Call limit : 2147483647 Callgroup : 1 Pickupgroup : 1 Callerid : "Arham Ali" <6000> ACL : No Sess-Timers : Accept Sess-Refresh : uas Sess-Expires : 1800 secs Sess-Min-SE : 90 secs Codec Order : (ulaw:20,gsm:20) Auto-Framing: No';
preg_match('/^.*Name\s?:\s?(.*?)\s.*Callerid\s?:\s?"(.*?)".*$/i', $string, $matches);
print 'CallerId="' . $matches[2] . '" Name= "' . $matches[1] . '"';
```

Comment: I had just typed in the same thing... You beat me to it!

Comment: you code need little correction

"preg_match('/^.*Name\s?:\s?(.*?)\s.*Callerid\s?:\s?"(.*?)".*$/i', $string ,$matches);"

Comment: @ArhamAliQureshi You are right. I forgot the $string in the second example: Thanks. I fixed it.